# Could not instantiate bean class org.springframework.validation.BindingResult

Tags: spring-mvc

I am getting the following exception in the `Spring` controller:

> Could not instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.validation.BindingResult]: Specified class is an
>   interface.

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class SendPasswordController {
    @Resource
     private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    //@Autowired
    //private UserService userService;
    @Resource
    private UserService userService;
    @Resource
    private ChangePasswordService changePasswordService;
    @Resource
    private EmailSenderService emailSenderService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/EmailForm" ,method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView sendEmail(@ModelAttribute(value="emailPasswordForm")
            BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request){ 
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("EmailForm");
        String userName= null;
        String password=null;
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            UserDetails userDetails =(UserDetails)auth.getPrincipal();
            userName=userDetails.getUsername();
            password=userDetails.getPassword();

            UserForm userForm = userService.getUser(userName);
            System.out.println("name is"+userName);
            System.out.println("password is"+password);
            User user=changePasswordService.findByNameAndPassword(userName, password);

            if(user!=null){
                  final String emailTo =user.getUserEmail();
                  final String subject = "Password Reset";
                  final String passwordGenerated = changePasswordService.randomPasswordGenerate();
                // for logging
                    System.out.println("emailTo: " + emailTo);
                    System.out.println("subject: " + subject);
                    System.out.println("message: " + passwordGenerated);
                    //System.out.println("attachFile: " + attachFile.getOriginalFilename());
                    //emailService.sendEmail(user, passwordGenerated);
                    mailSender.send(new MimeMessagePreparator() {

                        @Override
                        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(
                                mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
                            messageHelper.setTo(emailTo);
                            messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
                            messageHelper.setText(passwordGenerated);

                        }

                    });
                    emailSenderService.updatePassword(user, passwordGenerated);
                    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, user.getPassWord());
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                    return new ModelAndView("Result");

            }
        }
        return mav;
    }

}
```

This is my stack trace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.validation.BindingResult]: Specified class is an interface
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.validation.BindingResult]: Specified class is an interface
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveModelAttribute(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:762)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:356)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Comment: This code was working earlier.suddenly it has started showing this exception.

Answer (score 2):

I found a strange code in your controller:

```
public ModelAndView sendEmail(@ModelAttribute(value="emailPasswordForm")
        BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request){
```

If you you want to validate your form you should do something like this:

```
public ModelAndView sendEmail(
    @ModelAttribute(value="emailPasswordForm") EmailPasswordForm form,
    BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request){
```

Comment: i resolved the issue.it was the method signature.i changed it to@RequestMapping(value = "/EmailForm" ,method= RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView sendEmail(HttpServletRequest request)